# same code but error on web version in flutter. Why?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web, flutter-animation

in my flutter app when data adding from web version its shows error like this on mobile. but works fine on web, I use firebase as backend. why this is happening[image: here is the picture]

Comment: I had this issue, just cast to `in. It may happen because of render engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since web is transpiled to javascript, that has a type number (which receives both double and int). That problem maybe solved if you cast to right type.

You can learn more about how dart handles numbers in here:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers